# How to Boost The relevance dynamically(boost value get from database) in Tire elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch

if the search term provided by an end user contains any of the words or phrases (but does not need to be an exact match) contained in the **Decrease_Relevance_Text** field, then the relevance for that specific product is decreased by the amount in the **Decrease_Relevance_Points**

Comment: Just a small comment on coding style; I wouldn't mix `CamelCasing` and `under_scoring` in variable names. You will cause a lot of typos from and new devs joining your team!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
should do
 custom_score :script => "_score+doc['increase_relevance_points'].value" do
  boolean do
    should { match :increase_relevance_text, term}
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `boosting` query ([official docs here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/boosting-query/))

```
{
    "boosting" : {
        "negative" : {
            "match" : {
                "your_field" : "decrease_relevance_text"
            }
        },
        "negative_boost" : decrease_relevance_points
    }
}
```

I don't know how to create this specifically with tire though, maybe someone else can help you.

Comment: one more question..if i want to increase the relevance field for the same problem..that what will be the query..??

Comment: Three words: **[read the docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/boosting-query/)**. People like to help those who try help themselves! I even went to the trouble of linking the docs in my answer...

Comment: how can we give dynamic boost value for every search record ?

In my case every record in the database have a point value assigned to it,and i have to assign that point as boost value on its search.

Comment: I am using this solution
  custom_score do
            query do
              should { match :increase_relevance_text, term}
             # should { match :decrease_relevance_text, term}
            end
            script '_score+(doc.increase_relevance_points)'
          end
and I am getting error :- undefined method `query' for #<Tire::Search::BooleanQuery:0xb3c845d4>